# defaultValue option not selecting default value in Autocomplete Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
stateNPAValue[formData.state.vale] = 0: "All",1: "959", 2: "203",3: "860", 4: "475" // API response for NPA data

const [selectedNamesState, setSelectedNamesState] = useState([]);

const transformedNpaData = stateNPAValue[formData.state.value].map((label, index) => ({
    label,
    value: index.toString()  // You can use the index as the value or any unique identifier
  }));

<Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="fixed-tags-demo"
                name="Npa"
                value={selectedNamesState}
                onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                  setSelectedNamesState(newValue)
                  NPAHandler(newValue);
                  changeHandleStateErrorRemove(event)
                }}                
                options={transformedNpaData}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '')}
                defaultValue={[transformedNpaData[0].label]}
                renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
                  tagValue.map((option, index) => (
                    <Chip
                      label={option.label.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '')}
                      {...getTagProps({ index })}
                    />
                  ))
                }
                style={{ width: 500 }}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={formData.state.value} />}
                isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
                  return option.value === value.value;
                }}
              />
```

I wanted to select "All" as a default value in multiselect dropdown but defaultValue option is not working. Please let me know what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your `Autocomplete` component and your props are expecting the data type to be like below, and you are giving a correct type to `options` prop. I think `defaultValue` should also be the same type

```js
interface AutocompleteOption {
  label: string;
}
```

so I think changing the default value as below will solve the issue.

```js
// ...

<Autocomplete
    // ...
    defaultValue={[transformedNpaData[0]]}
    // ...
/>
```

Comment: I'm giving defaultValue like this but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering Autocomplete using controlled input. In such cases, you will have to set the default value in the useState that is controlling the selected values for Autocomplete. Read the doc [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#Autocomplete-prop-defaultValue). This is what its written in doc:

> defaultValue: The default value. Use when the component is not controlled.

Considering that the option `All` will always be on the top of the list. You can initialize selectedNamesState as follows:

```
const [selectedNamesState, setSelectedNamesState] = useState([
  {
    label: "All",
    value: "0",
  },
]);
```

Your options array in array of object, in case you are comfortable with converting it into array of string then the solution can be even simpler.

```
import { Autocomplete, Chip, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

const someKey = "someKey";
const stateNPAValue = {
  [someKey]: ["All", "959", "203", "860", "475"],
};

function App() {
  const [selectedNamesState, setSelectedNamesState] = useState(["All"]);

  const transformedNpaData = stateNPAValue[someKey];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="fixed-tags-demo"
        name="Npa"
        value={selectedNamesState}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setSelectedNamesState(newValue);
        }}
        options={transformedNpaData}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => {
          return option.replace(/[[\]']+/g, "");
        }}
        // defaultValue={[transformedNpaData[0].label]}
        renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) =>
          tagValue.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip
              key={option}
              label={option.replace(/[[\]']+/g, "")}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}
            />
          ))
        }
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="test" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: value just accept option.value property. so initial state just put '0'

Comment: The options props take an array of objects as input. So will have to keep the same item as the selected option.

Comment: I added initial value in useState but still value is not getting selected

Comment: Check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-test-vite-forked-nqq5wf): I have replicated the issue. @NehaRaghuvanahi

Comment: I tried that but still same issue. Actually I'm pushing "All" in API response because All is not coming in api response may be this is the issue.

Comment: When is Autocomplete rendered? Once the options are loaded from API or before that? The solution will be built based on when the options become available and when Autocomplete is rendered. @NehaRaghuvanahi

Comment: There are 2 other ways to solve it. The simpler one is to convert options into array of string, I added the code above and you can also check it in sandbox. Another it to avoid depending of option.value === value.value, instead use option.label === value.label in isOptionEqualToValue. @NehaRaghuvanahi